# Error while trying to install Git. "The following packages cannot be authenticated!"

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, git

(Just a bit of context: I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get the hang of the terminal and installing some programs on my PC. I was trying to install the media player mpv, but first it requested me to make sure that git is installed, so here I am.)

---

I typed git on the command line, and it said that the program was not installed. So I went ahead and:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

And then I got this:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-arch git-bzr git-cvs git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 258 not upgraded.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I gave the go ahead and it prompted me this:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  liberror-perl git-man git
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

If I type "n", it simply exits saying "E: Some packages could not be authenticated". If I type "y", it gives me this instead:

```
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main git-man all 1:1.8.3.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main git amd64 1:1.8.3.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_1.8.3.2-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_1.8.3.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I ran it with "--fix-missing", but after repeating all of the steps it again exited this time saying "Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.". So I went for the last option which was to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And this is what I got:

```
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                       
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease                     
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                             
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg                     
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg                   
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release                         
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release                       
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources/DiffIndex                  
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Sources/DiffIndex              
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex           
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise InRelease 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release.gpg                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease              
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release   
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg             
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main amd64 Packages             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release                
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main i386 Packages              
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources/DiffIndex 
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en             
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US  
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en     
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't know what to make of all of this. The last line is:

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I thought it might've done the trick but I retraced all my steps to install git again but got the same errors, so apparently it didn't work. I'm at a loss and I don't know how to proceed, help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of Ubuntu (saucy).  Packages for it are not supported anymore.  You will need to upgrade to a recent, supported version of Ubuntu first.

Here is how: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) (hat tip to @JonasCz).

Comment: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)